# I can’t understand why range functions increment argument applies to slicing operator

Tags: python, syntax, operators, slice

I’m trying to learn slicing operator and I’ve got a question.

```
kist = list(range(0,90,2))

bist = kist[::10]
print(bist)
```

For some reason this prints the multipliers of 20.
I realized that it was because i added '2' in the range function. But im trying to print multipliers of 10 without a for loop. I can do it with writing a 5 instead of a 10 but why? Why does the incrementer of range function apply to the slicing operator as well?

I’m writing in mobile. I couldn’t find how to put the code in a snippet. Also pardon my writing if I have any mistakes.

Edit: Okay, thanks everyone. I was working for hours and couldn’t grasp what was going on. Im pretty new to programming. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try printing `kist` and you'll get a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: You sliced every 10th even number.  Where is the confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty straightforward. Your

```
klist = list(range(0,90,2))
```

Generates a list of

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, ... 88]
```

Than when you slice every 10th element of it you end up with multiple of 20 for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

So, per its definition `range(start, stop[, step])` you have a range of:
`kist = [0, 2, 4, ... 86, 88]`
When you do `print(kist[::10])`, you're printing every N-th (i.e. 10th) element of your list. So, in your case it's:

```
your list: [0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, ..., 88]
item ID:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  ...
                         this one is to be printed ^^ due to your slicing every 10th item
```